# Use a custom generated string as a model field value in django

Tags: python, django

I want to search a keyword in multiple (about 20) forum-user databases.

Unfortunately, the specific tables are named differently throughout the databases. In one database, the user-table is named `username`, in another it is named `name` etc.

I added a model field `field_username` to every forum `field_username` which saves the corresponding value of each database.

```
{% for key, value in forum.items %}
    <p>{{ value.field_username }}</p>
{% endfor %}

<p>{{ user.customUsername }}</p>
```

I then want to use that `customUsername` as a model field value like this:

```
{% for user in value.user_list %}
    <p>{{ user.customUsername }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

... so that `customUsername` evaluates to the database value, like `username`, `name`, `display_name` etc.

Right now, nothing happens.
Is that possible?

Comment: You should call `.all` on the relatedmanager.

Comment: But perhaps it is better to share your models. I find it a bit odd that you have a table called "username" instead of storing the name in a field.

Comment: There are a few different approaches which can be taken here, but none of it is clear without more information.